# Box Shadow working once on site, but not again

Tags: html, wordpress, css, insets

Here's the CSS I'm using.

```
.hentry {
    padding: 40px 0;
    max-width: 840px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.hentry:before {
    box-shadow: -15px 0 15px -15px inset;
    content: " ";
    height: 100%;
    left: -15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 15px;
}
.hentry:after {
    box-shadow: 15px 0 15px -15px inset;
    content: " ";
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: -15px;
    width: 15px;
}


.widget-area {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 840px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: #cd0a2b solid 5px;
}
.widget-area:before{
    box-shadow: -15px 0 15px -15px inset;
    height: 100%;
    left: -15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 15px;
}
.widget-area:after{
    box-shadow: 15px 0 15px -15px inset;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: -15px;
    width: 15px;
}


.site-info {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 840px;
    padding: 30px 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: #cd0a2b solid 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.site-info:before {
    box-shadow: -15px 0 15px -15px inset;
    height: 100%;
    left: -15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 15px;
}
.site-info:after {
    box-shadow: 15px 0 15px -15px inset;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: -15px;
    width: 15px;
}
```

And the HTML

```
<article id="post-2" class="post-2 page type-page status-publish hentry">/article>

<div class="widget-area masonry" style="position: relative; height: 424px;"></div>

<div class="site-info"></div>
```

But for whatever reason the box shadow is only working on the widget-area. I've been on this for a few hours and can't spot anything wrong, but equally, can't work out how to make it work.

The box shadow code is originally from this Jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Qq5tQ/

Any ideas?

Edit: **Solution**

Right! I've fixed it. The solution was @Pete's using `position: relative;`, but it needed a bit more than that. For whatever reason, all of the `box-shadow` classes needed `content: " ";` on them, which was fine, except all of my afters were missing `top: 0;`.

After adding that in, it was simply a little bit of polishing to get my `.site-info` to work. Again, for reasons I do not fully understand, it about five pixels off the top (probably a padding issue I created earlier) but that was fixed with by altering the `top` and `height`, as seen below.

```
.site-info:before {
box-shadow: -15px 0 15px -15px inset;
height: 106%;
content: " ";
left: -15px;
position: absolute;
top: -5px;
width: 15px;
}

.site-info:after {
box-shadow: 15px 0 15px -15px inset;
height: 106%;
content: " ";
position: absolute;
right: -15px;
top: -5px;
width: 15px;
}
```

Thanks for all the help. I couldn't have done it without you both.

Comment: Try to add `.hentry:before, .hentry:after { content: ""; display: table; } .hentry:after{ clear:both;}`

Comment: Tried that. No luck what so ever I'm afraid. Please see my last comment to Pete for what I've been able to make work.

Comment: Just worked it out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have an item called `.entry-header` this needs to be changed to `.hentry` and you need to add `position:relative` to `.site-info`, `.hentry` and `.widget-area`

Comment: `.widget-area` already works and doesn't have  `position:relative`. Why?

Comment: @pappy, you have an inline style of position relative on that div

Comment: Here's what I've been able to work out. If I add `content: " ";` to each `box-shadow` class, it works, only the right hand side is pushed down a lot. Like this. http://i.imgur.com/TsvdOlR.png

Comment: In case anyone comes across this answer, I added the full solution into the main question. Thanks!